# Waterbottle cap still poping off

Tags: ford, cooling-system, fiesta

I have a 2008 Ford Fiesta 1.6i.  The car heats up and builds pressure in the water bottle that causes the cap to pop open and boiling water to come out.   I have taken it to Rord where they have done a pressure test on the block and there's no problems. They have checked the thermostat and no problem there.

So what could be the cause of the water bottle cap popping off?

Please give me some insight on what to do.

Comment: Is the temperature gauge showing a high temperature when it does this?

Answer (score 3):

Maybe cap or reservoir  has fractures inside and you don't notice it. When the pressure increases (which is normal) damaged teeth can't withstand that load. Try to change your water reservoir and it's cap.